# Getting error when creating an activity with coordinator layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, dependencies, android-coordinatorlayout

Just messing around with different kinds of layouts and wondering why this layout wont work. I downloaded the right dependencies and still getting an error. I want to use this layout because I read that you can position Snackbar with it. All the other layouts work in Android studio except this one. Following tutorials on coordinator layout use them with ease without getting no errors.

layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="maginatestudios.com.maginatecrate.test">

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Error log

```
04-25 18:04:43.544 6329-6329/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: maginatestudios.com.maginatecrate, PID: 6329
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{maginatestudios.com.maginatecrate/maginatestudios.com.maginatecrate.test}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                              Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
                                              Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:650)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:793)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:733)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                 at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:418)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2653)
                                                 at maginatestudios.com.maginatecrate.test.onCreate(test.java:11)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6980)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6540)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the design library.
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.ThemeUtils.checkAppCompatTheme(ThemeUtils.java:33)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:206)
                                                 at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.<init>(CoordinatorLayout.java:200)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Edit, my bad just saw the error down there

try to make your activity extend

```
AppCompatActivity
```

Comment: Looks like you have a problem with the theme, I updated the answer

Comment: Still no. Maybe you could try? Do people not use coordinate layout often?

Comment: Yes its popular, I am pretty much sure its a theme issue, maybe checking the styles.xml file and paste here what is the "AppTheme" extending there?

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: Awesome, replace `Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` with `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: Yeah that didn't work. I got this error : java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity. I have AppCompatActivity extended. I swtiched back to Activity and got the error I had before.

Comment: We are getting close, If you are not using "NoActionBar" delete the whole tag from the styles.xml. If all of doesnt work, I would start fresh project and paste the activity/layout code to the new one. Sorry I tried :)

Comment: Eh it's fine I just wanted it so I can position a snackbar. Thanks so much for the help though!

Comment: you were right. The style theme was causing the issue. I changed the style of AppTheme instead of the one that is in the Manifest, which is the NoActionBar. I changed it to @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar and it worked perfectly.